# How to Setup Bridged Routing with QEMU-KVM and Netplan in Ubuntu Server 20?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, libvirt, netplan

Very new stack exchange user here, so apologies in advance if I am breaking protocol in any way. Also I am still somewhat of a linux and routing novice so forgive my ignorance.

The basic problem is that I cannot get qemu-kvm, libvirt and netplan working together. It looks like they break each others network configs to me, but I wanted to put this question out to see if I'm perhaps just not using them correctly.

After installing ubuntu server 20.04.3 LTS my network interfaces and routes look like this (via "ip route"):

[image]

I install qemu-kvm, libvirt-daemon-system, libvirt-clients, etc, successfully. This adds a virtual bridge and virtual interface to the system:

[image]

Next I edit the netplan config file in /etc/netplan/<default.yaml>. This is my file:

[image]

It compiles successfully via sudo netplan generate, and is applied "successfully" via sudo netplan try, entering to confirm, but then... nothing. I look at the network interfaces and see this:

[image]

Existing IP addresses all lost. No bridge created, no interfaces joined.

I look at the routes and see this:

[image]

The routes have all disappeared except for the route to the virtual bridge. Looking back at the interfaces status, it looks like they have a working link layer, just no working routes.

Why did the routes disappear when I applied the netplan?

Am I doing this correctly? Or does anyone know of any current issues with creating/managing network interfaces and ip routes between QEMU-KVM, libvirt, and netplan?

Just FYI I've tried with a reinstall and different order of installation, successfully creating and addressing the bridge on nic#2, and then installing qemu-kvm and libvirt. The result is the netplan implemented bridge disappearing and the kvm virtual interface and bridge appearing as shown in img 4 above, and netplan able to be applied but no visible changes made, and all routes lost.

Thank you for your help with this!

UPDATE:
I've solved this issue for now by creating a startup script. I was not able to get the bridge to instantiate via netplan, but it seems to work if I create it beforehand manually using "ip link":

```
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
sudo ip link set eno1 up
sudo ip link set eno2 up
sudo ip link set eno2 master br0
sudo ip link set br0 up
sudo netplan apply
sudo dhclient -v -r
```

Here is the service file:

```
[Unit]
After=network.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/<username>/Scripts/netplanApply.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I also have a new netplan config.yaml file:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
        eno2:
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
    bridges:
        br0:
            interfaces: [eno2]
            macaddress: 11:41:14:11:41:14
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: false
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
```

In watching the verbose output at startup I think I can see that the "network services" service fails to startup (red) but its hard to tell. Is there a way to dump the verbose output at startup to a file for examination later on? Feels like the qemu-kvm or libvirt install is breaking the default networking config, or somehow interfering with netplan implementation on startup.